# Microsoft teams getting incoming call number

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

WE have a very simple use case where when a user is being called in the teams all we need is the number of the caller. The idea for us is to pass that number to our backend system and pop relevant information if it exists. so just need a way to read the number of the person calling.

i have looked at call records API but they will give info of already happened calls plus seems there is no event to subscribe when that happens.

is it supported?

Comment: This feature isn't supported at the moment. Please raise a user voice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this already? I'm looking for the exact same thing. :-)

Comment: nope i gave up on this as msft seems not supporting it

Comment: @MoblizeIT There's an interesting idea on the uservoice. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/7816f408-272e-ec11-b6e6-00224827bbc2 Maybe should all vote on it :-)

Answer (score 1):

As of(2/3/2021) we don't have this feature available. If you want this feature to be in future releases please raise a uservoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)