# Receive a request when Azure AD User receive a call

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there is a way to receive a request on an azure app whenever a User of a Azure AD group receive a call.

When a user create a [call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), the request returns an id that can be used to [Get call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I would like to do the same but with an entry call.

Comment: Can you share the flow/code you're using?

Comment: Don't really have code, I was trying to get the id with postman, but I only manage to get it when the call is completed. I want to have it when the phone rings.

Comment: Just found out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004973/microsoft-teams-getting-incoming-call-number . This is exatly what I need, shame it doesn't exist yet